# Hibernate: CalendarTime User Type

Tags: hibernate

How can we write CalenderTimeUserType for persisting a date in format "YYYYYMMDDHHMMSS"

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`